# Python reload with dynamic import (imp.load_source)

Tags: python, reload

I am using python2.5. I need to import a module dynamically and then reload on change. How do I achieve this.

I tried as in below example - does not work:

```
import imp
modfile = 'mymod_info.py'
modname = 'mymod'
modhandle = imp.load_source (modname, modfile)
reload (modhandle)
```

Static import and reload works (I am not looking for this):

```
import mymod_info as mymod
reload (mymod)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The load_source documentation is clear about initializing of already initialized module. Had missed the trivial aspect :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the module was already initialized, `imp.load_source` [will initialize the module again](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.load_source). So instead of `reload`, just call

```
modhandle = imp.load_source(modname, modfile)
```